# I nede if I Press the button the code Execute every 5 seconds

Tags: react-native

I nede if I Press the button the code Execute every 5 seconds
In other languages I use endlis  loop
and I put Inside  the loop sleep  function
this is my code

```
_onPress() {
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://myhost.org:800');
ws.onopen = () => {
// connection opened
ws.send("hi)
ws.close();
};
}
render() {
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
<Button
onPress={this._onPress.bind(this)}
title="open"
color="#841584"
accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
</View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `setInterval` on button click event like:

```
setInterval( () => { 
    //your code
}, 1000); // your interval
```

otherwise use one of these: https://github.com/fractaltech/react-native-timer or https://github.com/expo/react-native-timer-mixin